# Possible numeric codes

Tags: mathematics

This is a question I saw and solved a long time ago, it involves some maths.

There is a keypad

> 1  2  3
>
> 4  5  6
>
> 7  8  9

A certain password starts with a 3. Each digit is adjacent (horizontally or vertically) on the keypad to either of the previous two digits of the password. The password length is 10. How many possibilities are there?

For example, 1247879685 is valid but 1234565985 is not (4 is not adjacent to 2 or 3).

Note:
**Although a complicated combinatorics solution or a program would also work, I'm looking for one that any common person can understand.**

Comment: @Geobits Sorry, I meant either of the last 2 digits.

Comment: Is 32155 allowed? Is 322 allowed? (My understanding is no, yes respectively but wanting to check I've understood right)

Comment: @ChristopherFish You're right.

Comment: Do you have reason to think there's a nice answer?

Comment: @xnor I know a shorter method if a digit has to be adjacent to only the previous digit. I had originally thought the same approach would work, but it doesn't. So I have no idea whether a simple method exists or not.

Answer (score 3):

I made a small program in lua. this is the code:

```
n = {
[0] = {},
[1] = {[2]=true,[4]=true},
[2] = {[1]=true,[3]=true,[5]=true},
[3] = {[2]=true,[6]=true},
[4] = {[1]=true,[5]=true,[7]=true},
[5] = {[2]=true,[4]=true,[6]=true,[8]=true},
[6] = {[3]=true,[5]=true,[9]=true},
[7] = {[4]=true,[8]=true},
[8] = {[7]=true,[5]=true,[9]=true},
[9] = {[6]=true,[8]=true}}

function x(a,b, level)
  if level == 10 then
    return 1;
  end
  local newnumbers = {}
  for k in pairs(n[a]) do
    newnumbers[k] = true
  end
  for k in pairs(n[b]) do
    newnumbers[k] = true
  end
  local c = 0
  for k in pairs(newnumbers) do
      c = c + x(b,k,level+1)
  end
  return c;
end

print(x(0,3,1))
```

you can test it out at http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

The result is:

> 691,950

Not sure if I made any mistake

Comment: Is @SamDickson wrong then? And do you know the simpler approach - no code, very little math?

Comment: You tell me who is right. You should know. I could have made a mistake.  And I don't know the simpler approach.

Comment: I just realised my approach was wrong. Sorry. Shall I delete the question or just let it be?

Comment: But is the answer correct even, shouldn't a and b be removed from newnumbers ?