# No ordinary magic square part 2. How many solutions are there?

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

Same rules as last time except this time count or calculate the number of possible solutions!

[No ordinary magic square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35480/no-ordinary-magic-square)

Place 1-9 in the squares below in a manner such that none of the columns, rows or long diagonals have the same sum:

[image: empty 3-by-3 grid]

Comment: the other question is not too much old. It was only half an hour old. So you could just add this extra question in that.

Comment: @manshu If I did that how would I credit the first person to answer? I already marked an answer to my first question as correct so I cant take that back retroactively and credit the correct response to someone who answers the next question can I?

Comment: Maybe a bounty, but I'm not sure what privilege requirements are needed.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole only 75 rep. points

Comment: It seems reasonable to me for this to be a separate question.

Comment: I agree it should be a separate question.  Even though the questions are closely related, the methods one could potentially employ are quite different.

Comment: Yup. You solve the original one by playing with numbers until you make all the sums distinct. You solve this one by writing a computer program. (Of course you could solve the original one by writing a program too, but that feels like overkill.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the simple-minded 7-line Python program I just wrote, there are exactly

> 24960 solutions.

There is at least a 25% chance that I didn't make any stupid blunders.

Here's the code:

```
n=0
for p in itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = p
  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = [a+b+c,d+e+f,g+h+i,a+d+g,b+e+h,c+f+i,a+e+i,c+e+g]
  if a in (b,c,d,e,f,g,h) or b in (c,d,e,f,g,h) or c in (d,e,f,g,h): continue
  if d in (e,f,g,h) or e==f or e==g or e==h or f==g or f==h or g==h: continue
  n += 1
```

Why two separate lines for the inequality checks? Just because it looks better that way. Why change from `x in y` to `x==...` at the end? Out of a vague idea that it might be a bit faster.

It surprised me how quickly this ran -- but 9! isn't really all that large.

Comment: May you post the code? 7-lines sounds quite interesting.

Comment: @gareth I am new here so please advise me what to do. I took advice of another user to edit my first post instead of posting a 2nd question. Is there some way I can delete this puzzle and just leave the first?

Comment: Same result but waaaay more lines ;)

Comment: I would suggest that you leave it as two questions. Perhaps put a link in the first question to this one.

Comment: I am very impressed @GarethMcCaughan fast and efficient coding!

Comment: (But note that I am not an entirely uninterested party -- if you delete this question, I guess I lose the rep I gained from it.)

Comment: You can save 2 lines if you replace all the tests by if len([a+b+c,d+e+f,g+h+i,a+d+g,b+e+h,c+f+i,a+e+i,c+e+g]) == len(set([a+b+c,d+e+f,g+h+i,a+d+g,b+e+h,c+f+i,a+e+i,c+e+g])):

Comment: is it 3120 combinations if you remove rotations and mirrors (duplicates) of the combinations?

Comment: Every combination without exception is part of a set of size 8, so yes.

Comment: You can save one line replacing p in the for loop line directly with a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

Answer (score 7):

My Python code to iterate the solutions and their respective $8$ sums:

> ```
> def noms():
>     sums = set()
>     for p in permutations(range(1,10)):
>         for e in [p[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 9, 3)]
>                + [p[i:9:3] for i in range(3)]
>                + [p[0:9:4], p[2:7:2]]:
>             s = sum(e)
>             if s in sums:
>                 break
>             sums.add(s)
>         else:
>             yield p, sums
>         sums.clear()
> ```

Counting them:

> ```
> >>> sum(1 for solution in noms())
> 24960
> ```

Some more information:

> There are $8$ symmetrically isomorphic sets of $3120$ arrangements: $4$ rotations and $2$ lines of symmetry (reflection in one of the diagonals is the same as a rotation plus a reflection).
>
>  There are $1538$ different sets of sums distributed as:
>
> ```
> Sums  Count  Total
>  496    8     3968 
>  782   16    12512
>  102   24     2448
>  106   32     3392
>   10   40      400
>   36   48     1728
>    2   64      128
>    4   96      384
> ------------------
> 1538         24960
> ```
>
> An example of one the $496$ sets of sums that are unique up to symmetry is:
>  $\{9,11,12,13,15,16,19,23\}$
>  which is yielded by:
>
> ```
> 2  4  7
> 5  1  3
> 8  6  9
>
> 2  5  8
> 4  1  6
> 7  3  9
>
> 7  3  9
> 4  1  6
> 2  5  8
>
> 7  4  2
> 3  1  5
> 9  6  8
>
> 8  5  2
> 6  1  4
> 9  3  7
>
> 8  6  9
> 5  1  3
> 2  4  7
>
> 9  3  7
> 6  1  4
> 8  5  2
>
> 9  6  8
> 3  1  5
> 7  4  2
> ```
>
> The smallest sum of sums is $107$, which necessarily has $1$ or $2$ in the centre) and may be made in $88$ ways, or $11$ up to symmetry ($3\times 1+4\times 2$):
>
> ```
> 1  7  4
> 9  2  8
> 3  6  5  {8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19}
> -----------------------------------------
> 1  6  5
> 8  2  9
> 4  7  3  {6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19}
> -----------------------------------------
> 2  5  4
> 8  1  7
> 3  9  6  {8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18}
> -----------------------------------------
> 1  7  4
> 8  2  6
> 5  9  3  {6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18}
>
> 2  7  4
> 8  1  5
> 6  9  3  {6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18}
> -----------------------------------------
> 1  6  3
> 9  2  7
> 4  8  5  {8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
>
> 2  5  3
> 9  1  7
> 4  8  6  {8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
> -----------------------------------------
> 1  6  3
> 8  2  9
> 4  7  5  {8, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19}
>
> 2  5  3
> 7  1  8
> 4  9  6  {8, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19}
> -----------------------------------------
> 1  6  5
> 9  2  8
> 3  7  4  {7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19}
>
> 2  5  6
> 7  1  9
> 3  8  4  {7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19}
> -----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> The largest sum of sums is $133=8\times30-107$ and is the same set of squares where each of the $9$ digits, $d$, are replaced by $10-d$ and each of the $8$ sums, $s$, are replaced by $3*10-s$.
>
>  The lowest possible variance for the sums is $6.234375$, and there are $4\times 8=32$ such squares:
>
> ```
> 1  7  2
> 9  4  5
> 6  3  8  {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17  18}
>
> 2  5  6
> 9  8  3
> 4  1  7  {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
>
> 3  7  4
> 9  2  5
> 6  1  8  {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
>
> 2  5  8
> 7  6  3
> 4  1  9  {12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20}
> ```
>
> The highest possible variance for the sums is $22.25$, and there are $4\times 8=32$ such squares:
>
> ```
> 1  2  3
> 4  6  8
> 5  7  9  {6, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21}
>
> 1  2  3
> 5  7  9
> 4  6  8  {6, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21}
>
> 1  2  7
> 3  4  8
> 5  6  9  {9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20, 24}
>
> 2  1  7
> 4  3  8
> 6  5  9  {9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20, 24}
> ```